# Optional oneToOne relations and criteria field

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

**Introduction:**
Visitors can fill **reports** on my website.
Those report can either be filled by a **legalPerson** or a **naturalPerson**.

**Constraint:** I don't like empty fields and I would like to normalize as much as possible my database.
Hence, I have those relations:

[image: Database model]

**Question:** For these kind of optional relations, should I add the field notifier_type (we could call it a criteria field) in Report Object? I mean I can obtain a close result with:

```
if($this->getNaturalPerson) { 
    $notifierType = 'naturalPerson';
} ...
```

The only drawback would be that I can't query on notifier_type if it's not in DB.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: The way you have your FKs, a person (normal or legal) can file only one report and never more than one. I doubt that is your intention. Right?

Answer (score 1):

I'd put `person_id` as second field of `Report` and get rid of notifier_type. Then create a relation `persons` (persona?) with `id` field, then make foreign key from `Report.person_id` to `persons.id`.

This relation `persons` (persona?) would have all of fields from both your legal- and naturalPerson relations, plus one additional - `person_type`. You would have NULLs when a field would be not applicable for given type of person (namely legal_Statut would be NULL for natural person and birthday would be NULL for legal person).

I would then exclude `headquarters_address` and `home_address` and make additional relation `addresses` with `person_id` field - again, foreign key to `persons.id`. You would then have a possibility of assigning multiple addresses to persons, mark them as current or previous, whatever you wish. That's what I would do.

EDIT: Visualization

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answser. However your solution doesn't appear 3NF compliant. Each field on Report are not dependent only on the PrimaryKey -> if the legal persons field are n/a, the naturalperson field will be filled and the inverse is true.

Comment: Look at the picture and tell me what NOT depents on what, because I don't think I understand you, or you don't understand me.